# Convention for separating multiple arguments for a command line option?

Tags: standards, command-line-arguments

The GNU project has a [standard](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) for how command line arguments should look like. However, there is no description for what to do, when an option has multiple arguments. Is there a convention for a special character to separate those arguments?

Example:

```
--longOption="firstArg;secondArg" -s first;second
```

In my case, I need to be able to specify one option multiple times, which results in creating an object multiple times with different parameters.
This must be possible:

```
--longOption="allArgs;for;firstObject" --longOption="args;for;second"
```

I guess I would also need a way to escape that separation character somehow...

Comment: Often arguments are just listed twice: ```--longOption="firstArg" --longOption="secondArg"``` or ```-s first -s second```

Comment: Right, I saw that a few times. In my case the arguments control the parameters for object creation and need to be able to create multiple objects: --longOption="first1,second1" --longOption="first2,second2", so that will not work...